# Mongo search with populate in aggregation pipeline with text index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have one query regarding search implementation. Here search implementation or atlas-search is best suitable for search in a single collection. I think normally we faced a scenario where we need to search with populate or ref collection also. **How can I do it with better implementation?**

Consider the very simple scenario where I have 2 **collections**.

1 **Product**  (text index of product name field)

2 **User**  (text index on username fields may be firstName, lastName etc)

The user creates the products so in product collection there is ref on **createdBy** with user's MongoID.  On Frontend, there is a listing of products so I need to provide search criteria like below in single text search

1. I can search with product name
2. I can search with the name of the owner of the product

What is the best way to handle such a scenario with MongoAtlas?  ex. I want all products created by "Donni Bachhan". what is the aggregation pipeline you just or best practise for it

I have already asked the question with MongoDB community but not get proper help, please review below link for the community reference

https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-search-with-populate-in-aggregation-pipeline-with-text-index/6953

Answer (score 0):

Better I will explain it as steps

Step 1: match with user collections: There you will get user details

Step 2: lookup with product collections: with that, you will get the user-created all products.

Step 3: match for search, if there any search or filter needed to match this with product name

example:  (Hopefully this may help you)

```
    async function search(userid, query = null)
    {
      return await userModel
        .aggregate()
        .match({
          _id: userid
        })
        .lookup({
          from: "products",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "userid",
          as: "products"
        })
        .match({ $text: { $search: "cake" }  })
        .exec();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, It's a workaround, and I have already implemented this approach. But It's not the perfect solution for querying such things, considering I have thousands of data and I involve  this query then it's overkill little bit

Comment: And the second thing, I can't directly query to do User Model as there are lots of other filters I need to perform on Product Model. there are other ways to that.

Comment: I think then the better method is you need to perform all your filtrations in product collection with userid and then only `lookup` or `populate` user details

Comment: For text search, there is no mechanism to identify that user search for product name or user's first or last name. We can not do that. please review the details carefully so got some proper idea. wat exactly case is